# Using rsync to copy from local to remote server with cronjob, asking for password

Tags: ssh, scripting, rsync

I want to copy files from a local machine to a remote machine.

I have the command all set up and it looks like this:

```
rsync -a project root@123.456.789.0:~
```

However, when running this command, I'm prompted with a message to enter the remote server's password.

When setting this up as a cronjob it fails because the password is not entered.

What is way around this?  How can I create my cron job to run the command and enter in the password?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use public key authentication: on the server, add a line with the command run by rsync (for security) and your public key to `~root/.ssh/authorized_keys`. See the sshd(8) man page for information on the `authorized_keys` file format.

Comment: I added my local machine's SSH key and it still prompts for password.

Comment: Oops, did the opposite.